# How to link href to a TAB?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm using this example [CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/9nd4j/1724/).

I have a page with links using href. 
And I intend to add links to another page. When clicked on these links, automatically opening the TAB on the secound page, is it possible?

First page with Links:

```
 <a href="www.site.com/?page=about#tab1">TAB1</a>
    <a href="www.site.com/?page=about#tab2">TAB2</a>
```

Secound page with TABS

```
  Licenciaturas
<ul class="navi">
    <li><a class="menu2" href="#tab1">Eng Inf</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu3" href="#tab2">Eng Quimic</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu4" href="#tab3">Eng Civil</a></li>
</ul>
<br><br>
 Mestrados
<ul class="navi">
    <li><a class="menu2" href="#tab10">Mestrado 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu3" href="#tab11">Mestrado 2</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu4" href="#tab12">Mestrado 3</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu5" href="#tab13">Mestrado 4</a></li>          
    <li><a class="menu6" href="#tab14">Mestrado 5</a></li>
</ul>

<div id='tab1'>
   TEXTO LICENCIATURA 1
</div>
 <div id='tab2'>
   TEXTO LICENCIATURA 2
</div>
 <div id='tab10'>
   TEXTO Mestrado 1
</div>
 <div id='tab11'>
   TEXTO Mestrado 2
</div>

$('ul.prov').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
    //Change content displayed
    $($("ul.prov a.active")[0].hash).hide();      
    $(this.hash).show();

    //Change active item
    $("ul.prov a.active").removeClass("active");    
    $(this).addClass("active");  

    e.preventDefault();
});

//Hide all content divs except first one
$("ul.prov a").each(function(index){
    if(index != 0)
        $(this.hash).hide();
    else
        $(this).addClass("active");
});

$('a').click(function(){
   $("#tabs").tabs("option", "active", parseInt(this.id));
});
```

Comment: You can use a url parameter to pass the active tab and then intercept it in javascript and set your tabs accordingly. Is this along the lines of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: `target="_blank"` this will link it to a new tab

Comment: I don't want a new blank tab, for example, I want to link to tab2 with "TEXTO LICENCIATURA 2" text. Is that possible?

Comment: use hashtag in your URL like index.php#tab2

Comment: I am not quite sure that I understand your question, but if you are just wanting to use tabs on your page you can use JQuery - http://jqueryui.com/tabs/. If you want something to happen when those tabs are clicked you can simply hook up a clicked event in JQuery for that as well. If you are looking for another effect, please create a mock-up so we can see the intended action.

Comment: using  index.php#tab2 don't work.

Comment: I have 2 pages. One with links and another one with tabs. How to use href and link the first page to a specific tab on the second page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Please find the link below

http://jsfiddle.net/priyank_s/5x3yp6Lb/

you just need to use html and css


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>CSS3 tabs</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="tabs.css" />

</head>
<style>body
{
font-family: "Segoe UI", arial, helvetica, freesans, sans-serif;
font-size: 90%;
color: #333;
background-color: #e5eaff;
margin: 10px;
z-index: 0;
}

h1
{
font-size: 1.5em;
font-weight: normal;
margin: 0;
}

h2
{
font-size: 1.3em;
font-weight: normal;
margin: 2em 0 0 0;
}

p
{
margin: 0.6em 0;
}

p.tabnav
{
font-size: 1.1em;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-align: right;
}

p.tabnav a
{
text-decoration: none;
color: #999;
}

article.tabs
{
position: relative;
display: block;
width: 40em;
height: 15em;
margin: 2em auto;
}

article.tabs section
{
position: absolute;
display: block;
top: 1.8em;
left: 0;
height: 12em;
padding: 10px 20px;
background-color: #ddd;
border-radius: 5px;
box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
z-index: 0;
}

article.tabs section:first-child
{
z-index: 1;
}

article.tabs section h2
{
position: absolute;
font-size: 1em;
font-weight: normal;
width: 120px;
height: 1.8em;
top: -1.8em;
left: 10px;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
color: #999;
background-color: #ddd;
border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

article.tabs section:nth-child(2) h2
{
left: 132px;
}

article.tabs section:nth-child(3) h2
{
left: 254px;
}

article.tabs section h2 a
{
display: block;
width: 100%;
line-height: 1.8em;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
color: inherit;
outline: 0 none;
}

article.tabs section,
article.tabs section h2
{
-webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
-moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
-ms-transition: all 500ms ease;
-o-transition: all 500ms ease;
transition: all 500ms ease;
}

article.tabs section:target,
article.tabs section:target h2
{
color: #333;
background-color: #fff;
z-index: 2;
}</style>

<body>



<article class="tabs">

<section id="tab1">
    <h2><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></h2>
    <p>This content appears on tab 1.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum lacinia elit nec mi ornare et viverra massa pharetra. Phasellus mollis, massa sed suscipit pharetra, nunc tellus sagittis nunc, et tempus dui lorem a ipsum.</p>
    <p class="tabnav"><a href="#tab2">next &#10151;</a></p>
</section>

<section id="tab2">
    <h2><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></h2>
    <p>This content appears on tab 2.</p>
    <p>Fusce ullamcorper orci vel turpis vestibulum eu congue nisl euismod. Maecenas euismod, orci non tempus fermentum, leo metus lacinia lacus, nec ultrices quam ligula ac leo. Quisque tortor neque, vulputate quis ultricies ut, rhoncus mollis metus.</p>
    <p class="tabnav"><a href="#tab3">next &#10151;</a></p>
</section>

<section id="tab3">
    <h2><a href="#tab3">Tab 3</a></h2>
    <p>This content appears on tab 3.</p>
    <p>Sed et diam eu ipsum scelerisque laoreet quis in nibh. Proin sodales augue lectus. Maecenas a lorem a mi congue pharetra. Sed sed risus in nisi venenatis condimentum. Donec ac consectetur arcu. Integer urna neque, rutrum at pretium eu.</p>
    <p class="tabnav"><a href="#tab1">next &#10151;</a></p>
</section>

</article>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i sent the jsfiddle link,please follow that link.you can find the code there.

Comment: No, post your code in your answer. If jsFiddle ever goes away or is inaccessible, your answer loses all value. jsFiddle should *supplement* an answer, not be the sole source of it.

Comment: Hi, Work if the link is in the same page. But I have a different page with links, and another with tabs. Its possible to create a href on the first page to connect to a specific tab?